# Combining mark over ligature (Devanagari)

Tags: fonts, xetex, languages, ligatures

I want to typeset the combination m̐llo in Devanagari with XeLaTeX.
When I use the correct Unicode ल्ँलो, there is no ligature of the ls.
When I place the candrabindu on the ligature the o is not connected with theligature:  ल्लँो.

How can I get XeLaTeX to place the candrabindu on the ligature and get still the o in the correct position?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont{Siddhanta}

\begin{document}
ल्ँलो

ल्लँो
\end{document}
```

Here is an example from a textbook, how it should look like:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I’m not a student of Sanskrit, so my eye won’t be as sharp as yours, but the results look much better to me if I comment out `\usepackage{polyglossia}` and `\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}` and compile your example with either xetex or luatex.

Comment: Have you tried to typeset llom̐?

Comment: @Malipivo llom̐ looks nearly correct. But in my textbook the mark is above the ll-ligature and not above the o. I still think at least one of the examples should work. Probably it is a bug in the fonts I tried. The second example is at least rendered correctly in Opera browser (not in Firefox and Chrome), but I don't know which font it is using for Devanagari.

Comment: @sanskrit_learner Could you please add a snapshot (screenshot, scan or photo) of it from your textbook to the post?

Comment: @Malipivo see the excerpt of the textbook I added to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zdeněk Wagner, a Czech TeXist, who is not having enough points to post an answer at TeX.SX (or he is probably having different kind of problem), yet, is writing his observations:

1. The problem is not in `polyglossia` and `Language`, these commands are correct, the problem is in font loading. If you do not specify the script explicitly, the Latin script is assumed and thus the non-Latin characters cannot appear properly. What is missing is the script specification, you have to write

   `\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Siddhanta}`
2. Your example is wrong. All three characters, virama, candrabindu and o-matra, are dependent vowels, you cannot combine more than one of them with a consonant. If you type ल् (with a virama), you cannot add a candrabindu. If it is not an end of a word, you can only add another consonant. You can make a conjunct (ligature) with a candrabindu, i.e. ल्लँ but it must never be followed by any matra. In theory, you could add independent ओ but I cannot imagine how you would pronounce it. It looks really weird. You can, of course, nasalize a matra, e.g. ताँ, but if o-matra or ii-matra is to be nasalized, anusvara is used (merely due to graphical appearance).
3. There is an evident misprint in the textbook, the correct form is ताँल्लोकान्.
4. Try the following add-on to see which fonts are used by Firefox:
   https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fontinfo/

---

I am adding an example. The ligature `ll` is not having its Unicode code in all three fonts, so the result is correct from `xelatex` (left picture; all three cases) and once from `lualatex` (right picture; the first line).

```
% run: xelatex mal-chandas.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\def\maltext{ताँल्लोकान्\par}
% http://svayambhava.blogspot.cz/p/siddhanta-devanagariunicode-open-type.html
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Siddhanta} \maltext
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Chandas} \maltext
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit2003} \maltext
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe: xelatex]
[image: mwe: lualatex]

**Update:** We could use [`luaotfload`](http://ctan.org/pkg/luaotfload) package instead of [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package to get a correct form with `lualatex`; I used `script=devanagari` in document body then (I typed `taaMMllokaan` or `tAMMllokAn` at [Lexilogos](http://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/devanagari.htm)):

```
% run: lualatex mal-siddhanta.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\begin{document}
% http://svayambhava.blogspot.cz/p/siddhanta-devanagariunicode-open-type.html
% taaMMllokaan at Lexilogos
\font\malfont=Siddhanta:script=devanagari \malfont ताँल्लोकान्
\end{document}
```

Comment: Everybody can post answers.

Comment: He indeed did at least once. That's strange.

Comment: Thank you very much! Zdeněk Wagner's explanations seem very reasonable, why I didn't get the expected results. So the problem is in the textbook. On all occurences of the candrabindu in the book it is positioned on the ll.